# Taking information from one site and using it on my analyser/script made with PHP

Tags: php

I need to extract the "Toner Cartridges" levels from This [site](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18917575/index.php) and "send it" to the one im working on. Im guessing i can use GET or something similar but im new to this so i dont know how it could be done.

Then the information needs to be run through a if/else sequence which checks for 4 possible states. 100% -> 50%, 50%->25%, 25%->5%, 5%->0%.

I have the if/else written down but i cant seem to find any good command for extracting the infromation from the index.php file.

EDIT: just need someone to poin me in the right the direction

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?
Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Whats return this site? You can use file_get_contents('http://...');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the page you can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://example.com");
```

But in order to make the function work with URLs, [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) must be set to *true* in the config file of your php (php.ini)

Then you can use a [regular expression](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.regular-expressions.info%2F&ei=DnbwVKTEKYXxUJCThOAH&usg=AFQjCNHk2L00eyd2Ttnz7gdovKBeh3oJiQ&bvm=bv.87269000,d.d24) to filter the text and get data.
The php function to perform a regular expression is [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Example:

```
preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $host, $matches);
echo "domain name is: {$matches[0]}\n";
```

will output

```
domain name is: php.net
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are reading from a Printer Status Page.  In which case, to give your self the flexibility to use sessions and login, I would look into [Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).  Nice thing about Curl is, you can use the PHP library for code, but you can also test at the command-line rather quickly.

After you are retrieving the HTML contents, I would look into using an XML parser, like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).  Either one will get you to the information you need.  SimpleXML is a little easier to use for people new to traversing XML (this is, at the same time, like and very not like jQuery).

Although, that said, you could also hack to the data just as quick (if you are just now jumping in) with [Regulair Expressions](http://xkcd.com/208/) (it is seriously like that once you get the hang of it).

Best of luck!